# Can 'them' be used to indicate 'sentences'?

Tags: pronouns

1. In your last message, you have said to ask you questions about your sentences, if I failed to understand these.
2. In your last message, you have said to ask you questions about your sentences, if I failed to understand them.

In second sentence *them* has been used instead of *these*. Use of which one is better and why? I know that *them* is used both for *men* and *women*, while *these* is used for materials or non-human matters. So why second one is better than first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, delete the second comma; it's unnecessary.

*Them* as a pronoun is used all the time to refer to plural inanimate objects:

> My mom threw all my comic books away when I turned forty, but I still wanted to keep them.

So *them* substitutes for a previously mentioned plural noun (sentences, comic books) without adding any stress.

*These* is often used to distinguish one group of objects (animate or not) from a different group.

> I can understand the sentences you wrote yesterday but not *these* you wrote today.

This is why in your sentence, *them* works better than *these*.

> In your last message, you have said to ask you questions about your sentences if I failed to understand them.